# Getting 1 second sample using Xuggler

Tags: java, audio, xuggler

I have some issues regarding Xuggler API,

I want to create a little class, which once a mp3 file is opened, gets raw bytes from it, but, how many? I would like to have 1 second sample from the original file.

This is my current code:

```
public byte[] getSamples(int iBytesQtty){
    byte[] rawBytes = null;

    /** Go to the correct packet */
    while (this._inputContainer.readNextPacket(this._packet) >= 0){
        System.out.println(this._packet.getDuration());
        /** Once we have a packet, let's see if it belongs to the audio stream */

        if (this._packet.getStreamIndex() == this._iAudioStreamId){
            IAudioSamples samples = IAudioSamples.make(iBytesQtty, this._audioCoder.getChannels());


            //System.out.println(">> " + samples.toString());
            /** Because a packet can contain multiple set of samples (frames of samples). We may need to call
             * decode audio multiple times at different offsets in the packet's data */

            int iCurrentOffset = 0;

            while(iCurrentOffset < this._packet.getSize()){

                int iBytesDecoded = this._audioCoder.decodeAudio(samples, this._packet, iCurrentOffset);
                iCurrentOffset += iBytesDecoded;

                if (samples.isComplete()){
                    rawBytes = samples.getData().getByteArray(0, samples.getSize());
                }
            }
            return rawBytes;
        }
        else{
            /** Otherwise drop it */
            do{}while(false); /** WTF? **/
        }
    }
    return rawBytes; /** This will return null at this point */
}
```

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Actually this little piece of code, works for me, but not in all cases

```
Mp3File song = new Mp3File("sample.mp3");
        byte[] buff = null;
        int totalBytes = 0;
int iNumBytes = 1024;

        while( (buff = song.getSamples(iNumBytes)) != null ){
            totalBytes += buff.length;
    //      System.out.println("Length buff: " + buff.length + " TOTAL: " + totalBytes);
        }

System.out.println("Bytes: " + totalBytes + " (" + totalBytes/1024 + " Kb.)");
        float lengthSecs = (float) (totalBytes / ((1411*1000)/8)); 
        float lengthMins = lengthSecs/60;

        System.out.println("song duration: " + lengthMins + " mins. (" + lengthSecs + " secs.)");
```

I assume that the mp3 file it's actually internally converted to a regular WAV file, so per each second I have a 1411kbps rate. But as I said, it doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: *"get raw bytes from it, but, how many?, I would like to have 1 second sample"*  There is no way to tell how many bytes are required for 1 second of Variable Bit Rate MP3.  So basically you need to parse it back to sound first.

Comment: Actually, I think that by decoding it from the mp3 file, it kind of make the conversion between mp3 and byte values (that I think they're actually wav).

Although, there should be a way to doing so, what are you refering to "parse it back to sound first", could you be more specific, please.

And in the case the mp3 files are CBR?